# JavaScript - determine if two circles will intersect along their path

Tags: javascript, math, collision-detection, linear-algebra

```js
var circleA = {
 x: 100, 
  y: 40,
  radius: 20,
  color: '63, 81, 181',
  pathx: 220,
  pathy: 150
}

var circleB = {
 x: 250, 
  y: 50,
  radius: 30,
  color: '76, 175, 80',
  pathx: 120,
  pathy: 140
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = 500;
var centerY = 500;


//draw circle A
context.beginPath();
context.arc(circleA.x, circleA.y, circleA.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + circleA.color + ", 1)";
context.fill();

//draw circle A path destination
context.beginPath();
context.arc(circleA.pathx, circleA.pathy, circleA.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + circleA.color + ", 0.5)";
context.fill();

//draw line in circle A path
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(circleA.x,circleA.y);
context.lineTo(circleA.pathx,circleA.pathy);
context.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + circleA.color + ", 1)";
context.stroke();

//draw circle B
context.beginPath();
context.arc(circleB.x, circleB.y, circleB.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + circleB.color + ", 1)";
context.fill();

//draw circle B path destination
context.beginPath();
context.arc(circleB.pathx, circleB.pathy, circleA.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + circleB.color + ", 0.5)";
context.fill();

//draw line in circle A path
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(circleB.x,circleB.y);
context.lineTo(circleB.pathx,circleB.pathy);
context.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + circleB.color + ", 1)";
context.stroke();



//I NEED HELP HERE - i have no idea how to calculate this
function willCollide(ca_start, ca_end, cb_start, cb_end)
{
 var RSum = circleA.radius + circleB.radius;
  var t = 10;
  
  var a = getPos(circleA, t);
  var b = getPos(circleB, t);
  
  var distance = (a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y);
  var sum = RSum*=2;
  
 context.font = "20px Arial";

  context.fillText('distance: ' + distance + "  sum: " + sum,10,200);
}

function getPos(circle, t)
{
  //position changes
  var dax = (circle.pathx - circle.x);
  var day = (circle.pathy - circle.y);
  //normalize components
  var lenA = Math.sqrt(dax * dax + day * day);
  dax = dax / lenA;
  day = day / lenA;
  //position vs time
  var ax = circleA.x + dax * t;
  var ay = circleA.y + day * t;
  
  return {
   x: ax,
    y: ay
  }
}

willCollide(
 { x: circleA.x, y: circleA.y },
  { x: circleA.pathx, y: circleA.pathy },
  circleA.radius,
  { x: circleB.x, y: circleB.y },
  { x: circleB.pathx, y: circleB.pathy },
  circleB.radius
);
```

```css
body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have circles running around in space with a given path on each frame.

so I can say that circle A will go to xy(10, 8) and that circle B will go to xy(5, -3).

and I need to make sure the path each circle is going is clear and that there is no other circle that will go on that path, is so, I want to give it a new path.

I've attached an image explaining the situation and the desired result on each case.

your help is much appreciated. thank you!
[image]

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: ok @CertainPerformance, thank you! ive added code snippets showing where I'm at, I cannot do more then this cos I really have no idea how to calculate this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position of the first circle is described as

```
x1 = x1_0 + vx1 * t 
y1 = y1_0 + vy1 * t
```

where `x10` is initial x-coordinate, `vx1` is x-component of velocity vector, `t` is time.

Make similar expression for the second circle center, build expression for squared distance and find time when squared distance becomes equal to `4R^2` (for equal radii) - if solution exists at needed time interval, it is the moment of circles' collision.

In your designations (seems you have equal velocities):

```
RSum = circleA.radius + circleB.radius
//position changes
dax = (circleA.pathx - circleA.x) 
day = (circleA.pathy - circleA.y) 
//normalize components
lenA = Sqrt(dax * dax + day * day)
dax = dax / lenA
day = day / lenA
//position vs time
ax = circleA.x + dax * t
ay = circleA.y + day * t
```

and similar for `B` circle

Now make distance equation, substitute `ax, bx, ay, by` expressions and solve it for unknown `t` (quadratic equation, might have 0,1,2 roots)

```
(ax - bx) * (ax - bx) + (ay - by) * (ay - by) = RSum * RSum
or
(circleA.x + dax * t - circleB.x - dbx * t) * ....
```

Comment: thank you! .. I've added a code above, can you please show me how to implement your answer there?

Comment: ok, ive updated the code snippet base on what you wrote, but I get a little mixed up by what I need in order to get the end result. what am I missing?

Comment: You need to build and solve quadratic equation. I expand the first brackets, you need to expand all others at paper, simplify equation and make formula for solution.

Comment: sorry, I still haven't got a clue how to implement this, and I see everyone is keep on voting this post down, I guess I've asked the wrong question :/   -- any way, thank you for your time, I really much appreciate this.

Comment: No, your question is not wrong, but the first version did not contain own efforts

Comment: well, I've seen lots of examples in stackoverflow with the same type of question, it doesn't mean there was no effort - just that I didn't know how to tackle any type of calculation for this.. haha even now I have no idea what you wrote, I'm bad in math :D